# How to read the results of a LoadRunner test?

Tags: format, loadrunner

I'm using LoadRunner but I do not wish to use the Analysis tool of LoadRunner to do the results analysis.

I've found out that the results are stored in the `*.eve.gzl` files (in the `Result` folder), but the `*.eve` files doesn't seem to be readable even after unzipping `*.eve.gzl` via 7-zip.

What format are `*.eve` files based on?

Comment: Not sure why it was marked off-topic. This is actually one of the better question the tag "loadrunner" got. It doesn't "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" as  both the question and the suggested answer mention only LoadRunner tool which is exactly what the hashtag says.

Comment: If SO doesn't want LoadRunner related questions I will be happy to guide other users asking LoadRunner questions to the official LoadRunner support forum.

Comment: I think this question does ask for an off-site resource -- a file format specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot read the eve files as this is a proprietary format. Actually there are many more files that need to be read in order to decipher the eve files. What you can do is to open a new session with your results in Analysis tool that comes with LoadRunner. It will create a database file for you from the eve files based on the database you configured in the tool. You can then try to use this database to do your own analysis.

Comment: Well, I have got these results through what you say. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please consider marking this as the answer and givng +1 if it is the correct answer.

Comment: Hi, now I have another question, so please help me again! Can you explain the result files (*.mdb) as well as other files in the session I saved with Analysis tool? And in the *.mdb file, there are some tables with name as T12144412T that I don't know why they are named. Do you know? Thank you anyway!

Comment: I cannot explain this through comments on SO. If you would like to get more information please open a support ticket.

Comment: @Buzzy, What do you mean by *"It will create a database file for you from the eve files"*? Do you mean that there's a database output generated, or is the database only in "RAM" and used only by analysis?

Comment: IIRC there is a database output generated